# Brushed or Brushless DC motor for self balancing robot?

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, robot

I am looking to balance a robot using a flywheel connected to a DC motor (think of it as an inverted flywheel pendulum). Similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0312BNqIBFI

What I am unsure about is whether to use a brushed or brushless DC motor.

In this case torque control is important to maintain balance (I intend to do this by controlling the voltage and by knowing there is a relationship of voltage to current; and that torque is proportional to current).

The brushless motor seems more complicated to control. I am tending towards using a brushed DC motor (geared) but I am not sure if there is any disadvantage to using a brushed motor for this type of application? I am not concerned about longevity (i.e. brushes wearing out).

Comment: Some electrical noise from the commutator with a brushed motor. Are you planning on making the BLDC motor controller or sourcing one with the desired features? Makes a big difference.

Comment: Ideally I'd purchase a controller but it depends on the size. For the BDC, I assume a H-drive would be sufficient - cheaper and easier - correct?

Comment: Is using a stepper motor a feasible option?

Comment: Brushless motors are slightly more efficient (especially at high voltages), quite in electrical sense, serve longer. For small robots all these benefits are negligible though. Also at low speeds you wont be able to use sensorless brushless motors, so you'll need a brushless motor with hall sensors and controller for it and wiring will be trickier.